# Spring and Open JPA

Tags: spring, openjpa

I am looking for decent tutorials on integrating the spring framework with Open JPA.  Mostly for using connection strings and things like that.  Would you happen to have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a complete tutorial, but it might get you started: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/1945181) shows a sample configuration for a basic annotation-based Spring application with OpenJPA support.  I will attempt to expand it as I have time.